# 2 columns of values -> 1 column of values + 1 column of labels in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

what's the most elegant way of achieving this in one line using pandas?

starting point:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0.2,0.3,0.1,0.45], 'B':[0.5,0.8,0.15,0.55]})

i   A     B
0   0.2   0.5
1   0.3   0.8
2   0.1   0.15
3   0.45  0.55
```

desired endpoint:

```
i   value  label
0   0.2    A
1   0.3    A
2   0.1    A
3   0.45   A
4   0.5    B
5   0.8    B
6   0.15   B
7   0.55   B
```

Comment: In the output index 2 supposed to be `0.1`? Is `0.15` a mistake? BTW: what have you tried so far?

Comment: thanks for spotting that. ive fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
pd.melt(df)
Out: 
  variable  value
0        A   0.20
1        A   0.30
2        A   0.15
3        A   0.45
4        B   0.50
5        B   0.80
6        B   0.15
7        B   0.55
```